# Remove first gallery in post content in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Despite of looking so simple, I don't know why the below code doesn't removes the first gallery from the post content.

```
function remove_slider($content){
    $c=str_replace(get_post_gallery(),"",$content);
    return $c;
}
add_filter("the_content","remove_slider");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function wpse125903_remove_the_first_gallery( $output, $attr )
{
    // Run only once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Override the first gallery output        
    return '<!-- gallery 1 was here -->';   // Must be non-empty.
}

add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'wpse125903_remove_the_first_gallery', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Works very well.

Comment: glad could help bro :)